# Delete item from list of tuples and move items up

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I want to delete an element from a list of tuples and move the other items that had the same position.

Input:

```
a=[('201001', '-4'), ('201002', '2'), ('201003', '6')]
```

Desired output:

```
a=[('201001', '2'), ('201002', '6'), ('201003', 'na')]
```

I have tried the following code for it:

`a[0](:- 1)`

But I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I would appreciate it if you could suggest ways to solve this case.

Comment: 1: square brackets are used for indexing, not parenthesis. you had it right with `a[0]`, but then you would want `a[0][:-1]`. This is the syntax error. 2: tuples are immutable, and cannot be changed. You need to rebuild a new one with the correct contents if you want to modify a value. There you would use round parenthesis, which can be used for constructing a tuple: `a[0] = (a[0][0], a[1][1])`. Better yet, use a list of lists, so the contents can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each element and set the tuple so that the second value is the value of the next element (except the last element because there is no element after it)

```
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    try:
        a[i] = (val[0], a[i+1][1])
    except IndexError:
        a[i] = (val[0], "na")
```

instead of error catching, you could also use the index:

```
arr_len = len(a) - 1
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if i == arr_len:
        a[i] = (val[0], "na")
        break
    a[i] = (val[0], a[i+1][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `zip`:

```py
a = [('201001', '-4'), ('201002', '2'), ('201003', '6')]

output = [(x, y) for (x, _), (_ ,y) in zip(a, [*a[1:], (None, 'na')])]

print(output) # [('201001', '2'), ('201002', '6'), ('201003', 'na')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way that lets you choose where you want to delete your number:

```py
a = [('201001', '-4'), ('201002', '2'), ('201003', '6'), ('201004', '8'), ('201005', '3')]

def delete_item(position, arr):  # position starting at 0, [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), etc]
    newNums = ([arr[x][1] for x in range(0, position)] 
               + [arr[x][1] for x in range(position+1, len(arr))] 
               + ['na'])
    arr = [(arr[x][0], y) for x,y in zip(range(len(arr)), newNums)]
    return arr
    
newTuple = delete_item(3, a)
```

Ouput:

```
[('201001', '-4'),
 ('201002', '2'),
 ('201003', '6'),
 ('201004', '3'),
 ('201005', 'na')]
```

Then you can keep putting the list of tuples in to remove a new number at a new position:

```
newTuple = delete_item(1, newTuple)
```

Output:

```
[('201001', '-4'),
 ('201002', '6'),
 ('201003', '3'),
 ('201004', 'na'),
 ('201005', 'na')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are referenced the same way as a list which is `a[0][-1]` for the last element of the first tuple.
As tuples are immutable, you would be creating a new tuple every time you want to edit one.

One answer to your question would be to iterate through the values and update them like in the other answers.

A simpler way could be to first convert it into two lists, update and zip them back, like so:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
fst = list(map(lambda x: x[0], a))
snd = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))
snd.pop(0)
a = list(zip_longest(fst, snd, fillvalue='na'))
```